# Remove Ads Banner and can not make App becomes Full Screen

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, iad

My apps has a Root View Controller that contains Container View and Ads Banner. Container View's bottom is pinned to Ads Banner's top  using Auto Layout.

My requirement is  when Ads Banner is removed, the container view must resize to full screen.

I can't do it. I removed Ads Banner by either set it to nil or remove it from superview. But the Container View still remains the same size and same position,  leaving a blank space at the bottom where Ads Banner was.

I also tried set new constraint to Container View with this code

```
containerViewBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view.superview, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

But then the App crashes with this error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A multiplier of 0 or a nil second item together with a location for the first attribute creates an illegal constraint of a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs.

[image: RootView]

Comment: FYI, Apple said: **["The iAd App Network will be discontinued as of June 30, 2016. "](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say that the Ad Banner height is 50, so just get the bottom constraint of the container view as an outlet to your class.

Then adjust the constraint by doing like:

```
containerViewBottomConstraint.constant = -50
```

You might need to call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in order to refresh the view with new constraint.

Good luck !

Comment: Thank you.  Just change the constraint to pin to Bottom layout guide instead of Ads banner.   and set it to 0 in viewWilAppear

Now container is full screen.

But it brings new problem.
I delete App from device to clear in-app purchase history  and  re-install it from Xcode.    Now  App crashes in AppDelegate with below error.
 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ADBannerView must be part of a view hierarchy managed by a UIViewController'

please advise.

Comment: @AeyKungTaemin please give me more details !

Comment: I know what causes error.

I put self.canDisplayBannerAds = true   in viewWillAppear.
Previously, i put it in viewDidLoad.

But should i put it.  because i add Ads Banner via IB already.

Comment: @AeyKungTaemin you can add canDisplayAds only when you need to , even if you have an outlet ! If it's not needed then don't add it .